# Performance entre criar vários objetos ou só um

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, desempenho

Sempre tive uma dúvida referente aos blocos de código abaixo, qual se comportaria mais rápido levando em consideração o serviço:

```
foreach(var t in listaT)
{  
 using(TService service = new Tservice())
 { 
    t = service.Find(t.Id)
    t.ValorPontuacao = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((t.ValorR / t.Valor) * t.ValorP), 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
    listT.Add(t);
 };  
} 

using(TService service = new Tservice())
{
 foreach(var t in listaT)
 { 
  t = service.Find(t.Id);  
  t.ValorPontuacao = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((t.ValorR / t.Valor) * t.ValorP), 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
   listT.Add(t);
 }
}
```

O trecho de código é somente um exemplo, gostaria de saber qual é mais performático, sabendo que o segundo exemplo daria "menos" trabalho para o garbage collector. Deixando claro que o `TService` é uma sobrecarga do `AbstractService<TDAO,T>`, vale salientar que a classe `T` é somente um exemplo e a lista será manipulada posteriormente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando esse código olhando simplesmente em **como** você ta fazendo, sem olhar **o que** você ta fazendo, de forma bem pragmática, em pouquíssimos cenários o primeiro seria melhor que o segundo, levando em conta que o primeiro fará N instanciações de um mesmo objeto, gerando mais trabalho para o GC a troco de nada.

Agora olhando para o **o que** você está fazendo, ai teríamos vários bottlenecks, como fato de você estar fazendo um **find** que provavelmente faz uma consulta ao banco para cada T na listaT, você poderia fazer uma consulta especializada no service que esperasse uma lista de Ids, e retornasse uma lista de **t**.
O fato de você estar dando **new** em um service, já mostra que não está usando Dependency Injection que já resolveria problemas de construção de objetos na sua aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de uma série de questões, não dá para responder sem conhecer os detalhes de implementação de cada coisa.

De fato é provável que o segundo seja mais performático porque ele não só não faz vários instanciações, mas também gera menos objetos e por isso menos pressão para o *garbage collector* por tanto ele gerará menos pausas e menos trabalho para o GC. Quando mais objeto é criado no *heap* pior para o GC. O primeiro parece criar um só objeto.

Se não ficou claro, cada `new` gera um objeto novo que será descartado logo depois. Eu só não posso dizer se precisa criar esse objetos ou não, cada objeto pode ter uma semântica diferente. Se um objeto só é possível fico pensando se precisaria mesmo cria um objeto ou isso deveria ser estático, mais um erro possível deste código.

Existe uma mínima chance desse `TService` ser uma `struct` isso poderia mudar um pouco essa explicação porque não coloca pressão no GC, mas ainda seria ligeiramente pior no primeiro caso. E nada indica que seria isto, mas poderia, afinal talvez possa ser que nem `class` e `struct` parece ser necessário aí. Claro, estou especulando, a pergunta não é clara para afirmar sobre isso.

Nem vou entrar no mérito que está alterando o objeto do iterador do laço porque isso é outra questão e imagino que o código foi feito só para exemplificar, mas é um exemplo ruim, que não faz nada útil, então em última análise, ambos são bem ruins por igual, mesmo que um deles gere mais esforço. Então não adianta muito entender um erro do código se ele possui vários outros.

A edição mostra que o código não faz sentido e nem deveria fazer nada disso, portanto o problema nem é a performance.

Comment: Entendi, perdão por exemplificar um código ruim. Irei acrescentar mais detalhes no código para melhorar a pergunta.